# apt-get: cannot configure (current status `half-installed')

Tags: apt

I can't seem to get rid of this error:

```
~ » sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 package libqt4-svg:i386 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I try:

```
~ » sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 package libqt4-svg:i386 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-svg:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I fixed it by reinstalling it:

```
~ » sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt4-svg:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libqt4-svg:i386.
(Reading database ... 153417 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqt4-svg_4%3a4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-svg:i386 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) over (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libqt4-svg_4%3a4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-svg:amd64 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) over (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libqt4-svg:i386 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libqt4-svg:amd64 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```